# How to extract the first x digits out of a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I would like to extract the first 5 digits out of a given nxm matrix.

For example the 3x3 Matrix A

```
A = [[ 1.  2.  3. ]
     [ 4.  5.  6.]
     [ 8.  9.  10.]]
```

The first 5 digits would be 1,2,3,4,5, so the first row and the half of the second.

The big problem is to do that without using too much resources, the brute force solution is too expensive.

Comment: Just use `a.flat[:5]`, don't bother with a reshaping solution, you don't need to do that much.

Comment: @user3483203 oh nice, I didn't know about `flat`. That could definitely be its own answer.

Comment: @user3483203 I agree with Ruzihm you should put it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reshape with shape of `(-1,)` then slice to `x`:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)) 
print (A)

x = 5
B = A.reshape((-1,))[:x]
print (B)
```

> ```
> [[0 1 2]
>  [3 4 5]
>  [6 7 8]]
> [0 1 2 3 4]
> ```